# Filtering a Material Table with numbers ranges [Angular 7]

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular7, angular-material-table

I am using Material Table on my Angular 7 project.

I have a table that displays several objects.

Each object has a property 'number of promotions' and i would like to filter this table using numbers ranges (under 5, from 6 to 10, from 11 to 20, more than 20).

Here is an example of the dataSource.filterPredicate I used to have custom filters on my table but i don't get how to manage the one i explained earlier...

```
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: Store, filter: string) => {
      switch (this.filterCriteria) {
        case 'approval':
          if (filter === 'null' || filter === '') {
            return (data);
          } else {
            return (data.approval.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1
            );
          }
```

Comment: you can add your original datasource and expected output, it will be easy for us to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to solve my problem, and i was very very very simple. -_-'

I just had a case to my switch with the correct filter on my dataSource.filterPredicate.

```
      case 'promotion':
          if (filter === 'null' || filter === '') {
            return (data);
          } else {
            switch(filter){
              case '5':
              return (data.total_promotions <= 5);
              case '10':
              return (data.total_promotions > 5 && data.total_promotions <= 10);
            }
          }
      }
```